# How to get separate links of yii2 sort low to high and high to low

Tags: php, sorting, yii2

I have a sort by price and date in my yii2 like

```
Sort by : <?=$sort->link('price');?> | <?=$sort->link('date');?>
```

It gives an output of something like this [check this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6Bu9.jpg)
I can sort with price by clicking the price tag.Same link for both low to high and high to low.
I want separate link for both like

```
low to hight | high to low
```

How to do this

Answer (score 0):

@abhi If you want to add the filter by price and date above the grid in view page then you need to prepare URL parameter like below:

For Low to high for price:

```
http://example.com/project/index?sort=price
```

For high to low for the price

```
http://example.com/project/index?sort=-price
```

Need to follow the same process for date attribute. And make sure the date and price attribute are available in ActiveRecord.